# To check whether the css3 and/or HTML5 property is supported by browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check whether the **"contenteditable" or any HTML5 property is supported** by user browser or not ?

So here is my JavaScript:

```
var isEditable=false;
function chk() {
    var z=document.getElementById("mydivid");

    if(typeof(z["isContentEditable"])==="boolean") {
        isEditable=true;
    }
}

function doEdit() {
    chk();
    var z=document.getElementById("mydivid");
    if(isEditable) {
        z.setAttribute("contenteditable","true");
        z.focus();
    } else {
        /* add a texbox and put all div's innerHTML into it, All in all:  a Boring Stuff. */
    }
}
```

And Here is HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doEdit();">Click To Edit </a>
<div id="mydivid"> Hi Ssup ?? <img src='' alt="some image" /></div>
```

Can Anyone tell me Whether My Approach is right ? Will it work in IE(version<8.0) ? And Also A better approach is needed !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To chcek if any propery exits for a element. You can do this

```
var element = document.createElement('__ELEMENT__');
if ('__PROPERTY__' in element ) {
    // property supported in the browser
}
```

**or**

```
if ('__PROPERTY__' in document.createElement('__ELEMENT__') ) {
    // property supported in the browser
}
```

The below link contains it all.

1. https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/570
2. http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#contenteditable

Answer (score 7):

Simple check:

```
if ('isContentEditable' in document.createElement('span')) {
    // supported
}
```

I will also share this great selection of snippets it will help you in future: http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html

Comment: Thanks For Sharing Such a Great Information !